# How does ADO.NET store dates and time?

Tags: sql, datetime, ado.net, utc

I was lazy and write an insert statement with DateTime.Now. It occur to me later i should have written DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(). This got me thinking, does ADO automatically convert dates into universal time? and restore it to local when i pull data out? Or do i need a write ToUniversalTime and ToLocalTime myself in every area of code? How should i manage time properly on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` structure contains the `Kind` property that specifies if the value is a local time or an universal time (or unspecified).

When you store the date in a database it's only the date and time components that are stored. The `Kind` component is lost, so when you read the `DateTime` value from the database you can't tell if it was a local or a universal time that was stored.

I recommend that you store universal time in the database, and also put "UTC" in the field name to make it obvious what's stored in the field, for example `CreatedUtcDate`.